# Tensorflow predict using Nodejs Api

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm using NodeJS tensorflow Api via `require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node")`.

I'm trying to make a model, train data using that model ad then predict "label" for unseen data using that model.

So far, it looks I can load data and train them successfully.
But I'm having issues on predicting another data, certainly because I misused the tensors, and I'd need some help to understand tensorflow correctly.

I won't give details about the model itself as I guess it is not involved in the issue. (maybe I'm wrong ?)

Here is the process I have set :

1. Data I get from a database are in the following format: `[{ x: 20, label: "some label", time: '2023-02-12 10:45' }, { x: 22, label: "some other label", time: '2023-04-12 10:42' }]`
2. I then load, normalize, transform, batch
   And the functions looks like :

```
const normalize = (n) => {
    if (!n || typeof n.x==="undefined") { return null; }
    // getIndexedLabel returns an index from the 'labels' Array
    let index = getIndexedLabel(typeof n.label!=="undefined"?n.label:0);
    return res = {
        xs: (parseFloat(n.x) - min) / (max - min),
        ys: typeof index!=="undefined"?index:0
    };
};
const transform = (t) => {
    const zeros = (new Array(numOfClasses)).fill(0);
    return {
        xs: tf.tensor(parseFloat(t.xs), [1], "float32"),
        ys: tf.tensor1d(zeros.map((z, i) => {
            return i === t.ys ? 1 : 0;
        }))
    };
};
```

3. And then I "train" using `model.fitDataset(data, )`
   In the end I got a accuracy and a loss.
4. Once completed, I'm trying to predict an unseen data like the following: `[{ x: 21, }]` (yes I don't care about the time yet since I'm trying to "predict" the label according to the x value)
5. Whatever I do in the data passed to predict I can't get an output. The script give me errors about tensors or datatype or whatever.. depending about what I have passed to "predict".

I believe the values send to `predict` is not correct. Could you point me out if at least I'm understanding correctly ? And could you give me more explanation about my mistake ?

Thanks a lot.